# dynamic range of columns as dimensions

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

Harvest stats

```
         2020-01.  2020-02. 2020-03. 2020-04.
Apples      2         3         3       4    
Oranges     3         1         2       6
```

I would like to draw a timeline plot in datastudio with the dates in the X axis and #of fruits in the Y-axis? Is there any way to specify a range of columns as dimensions as opposed to manually adding them to the dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Your source is Google Sheets? Yes, then add another sheet and paste the values from the first one transposed.

Data Studio itself cannot pivot / unpivot data.

[image]